# How to get Facebook checkin using Facebook Graph API or any other method

Tags: facebook-graph-api

1. Hi i am need to all facebook check data but i did not found any
   sollution for this
          i am using this
          https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/locations?access_token=$access_token
          https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/checkins?access_token=$access_token
          but receiving

   ```
      {   "error": {    "message": "(#12) checkins API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher",    "type":
   ```

   "OAuthException",    "code": 12   } }

Please give me alternate sollution for getting facebook checkin

Answer (score 2):

It´s deprecated and there is no alternative. Checkins don´t exist with a direct API anymore, you can only do a checkin with a wall post by including a place.

Comment: How do you query all the check-ins of your facebook page ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Hello all,

   I found an alternate solution for this

   please use this graph api

   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/tagged_places?access_token=$access_token

   $json_locations
   =file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/tagged_places?access_token=$access_token");
   $locations = json_decode($json_locations, TRUE);
   foreach($locations['data'] as $key => $jsons) {
   if(!isset($jsons['status'])) {  $jsons['status']='-'; } 
   if(!isset($jsons['place']['id'])) {     $jsons['place']['id']='-'; }
   if(!isset($jsons['place']['name'])) {   $jsons['place']['name']='-';
   } if(!isset($jsons['place']['location']['city'])) {
       $jsons['place']['location']['city']='-'; }
   if(!isset($jsons['place']['location']['country'])) {
       $jsons['place']['location']['country']='-'; }
   if(!isset($jsons['place']['location']['latitude'])) {
       $jsons['place']['location']['latitude']='-'; }
   if(!isset($jsons['place']['location']['longitude'])) {
       $jsons['place']['location']['longitude']='-'; } $type= 'checkin';
   $checkin_id=mysql_real_escape_string($jsons['place']['id']);
   $name=mysql_real_escape_string($jsons['place']['name']);
   $city=mysql_real_escape_string($jsons['place']['location']['city']);
   $country=mysql_real_escape_string($jsons['place']['location']['country']);
   $latitude=mysql_real_escape_string($jsons['place']['location']['latitude']);
   $longitude=mysql_real_escape_string($jsons['place']['location']['longitude']); //echo "update set user_registeration
   latitude='$latitude',longitude='$longitude' where
   face_book_id='$id'"; if($type=='checkin' || $type=='status') {
   $check=mysql_query("select * from fb_checkins where
   facebook_id='$facebook_id' and type='$type' and name='$name' and
   checkin_id='$checkin_id'") or die(mysql_error());
   if(mysql_num_rows($check)>0) {          $fetch1=mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
       $id=$fetch1['id'];  $delete=mysql_query("delete from fb_checkins
   where id='$id'"); $sql=mysql_query("insert into fb_checkins set
   facebook_id='$facebook_id',name='$name',checkin_id='$checkin_id',type='$type',city='$city',country='$country',latitude='$latitude',longitude='$longitude'")
   or die(mysql_error());

   } else {    $sql=mysql_query("insert into fb_checkins set
   facebook_id='$facebook_id',name='$name',checkin_id='$checkin_id',type='$type',city='$city',country='$country',latitude='$latitude',longitude='$longitude'")
   or die(mysql_error()); } } }

   1. List item